# How to parse a JArray into JObjects, get the first 4 letters of a string of the JObjects and save them back in a JArray

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am using a postcode related API service, where you can get all other postcodes within a given distance of a given postcode.

The following is an example of the `Json` results

```
{
    "postcode":"******",
    "lat":111111111,
    "lng":11111111,
    "distance":0.0        
},
{
    "postcode":"******",
    "lat":2222222222,
    "lng":2222222222222,
    "distance":0.0343
}
```

I am using the following in my `API Controller`

```
public object GetPostcodesWithin(string postcode, double distance)
    {
        var trimPostcode = postcode.Trim();
        var url = "some url" + trimPostcode + "&miles=" + distance + "&format=json";
        dwml = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        dynamic jsonData = JArray.Parse(dwml);
        var response = jsonData;

        dynamic secondps = jsonData[1];
        string newps = secondps.postcode;

        JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        var postcodes = from p in rss["{ }"]
                        select (string)p["postcode"];

        JArray finalPostcodes = new JArray();
        // List<string> finalPostcodes = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in postcodes)
        {
            var firstletters = item.Substring(0, 4);
            finalPostcodes.Add(firstletters);
        }
        return finalPostcodes;

        //int length = response.Count;
        //for (int i = 0; i < response.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    var item = (JObject)response[i];

        //    // JObject o = JObject.Parse(response);
        //}

        //for (int i=0; i< dwml.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    JToken t[i] = JToken.Parse("{}");

        //}

        //JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

        //var postTitles =
        //from p in rss["channel"]["item"]
        //select(string)p["title"];

        //foreach(var item in postTitles)
        //    {
        //        Console.WriteLine(item);
        //    }

        // return Json(newps);
    }
```

All the commented out sections are different things I have tried. Basically I get the dynamic `Json` data, but at this line `JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jsonData);` it fails. Goal is to get only the first 4 letters of the postcode attribute of each object in the `JArray`, save it in another `JArray` or `List` so I can use it for querying matching data from the database of the `MVC` web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
string yourJsonData = // your json array
var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(yourJsonData);

var resultList = new List<string>();
foreach(var jsonObj in jsonArray)
{
    dynamic obj = jsonObj;
    string postcode = obj.postcode;

    resultList.Add(postcode.Substring(0,4));
}
```

it will go through all returned items, get the first 4 characters in each postcode and store it in `resultList`.

Comment: A semi column is missing, but works perfectly. Thanks `resultList.Add(postcode.Substring(0,4));`

Comment: Thanks for the missing semicolon. Will add to the answer. Was glad to help.